# How can i get the google SERPs? A newbie question

Tags: java, kotlin

i tried to get the SERPS (search Engine Related Pages) from Google with Kotlin/Java, but trying to use the HTML pages and search is a little bit difficult. Is there any way to get, the first 100 results as a variable or array. just something that can be worked with. I need this for an idea of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read that -> https://www.webrankinfo.com/dossiers/google-search/serp

And use : Jsoup -> https://github.com/jhy/jsoup

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me a lot :)